# Xcode 12.5.1 - Could not attach to pid: "####" - Lost Connection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KIOo.png)

I am getting this error message whenever I try to run any of my iOS projects on the simulator. How do I get rid of this?

I have already tried Cleaning the build folder, and erasing all content and settings of the simulator, tried different simulators as well as closing and starting the Xcode again.

```
Details

Could not attach to pid : “3386”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: lost connection
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "lost connection";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.0 (Build 21A5304g)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-08-25T12:20:16+05:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be related to the beta version of macOS that you use.

I suggest using the [Xcode 13 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/download/) from Apple for developers.
You need a free apple developer account to access this download.

For me this solved all problems.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with authorization, Try below lines in terminal.

**sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable**

Comment: already tried this, nothing changed with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was getting this error in the console:

`com.apple.debugserver) may not get the task control port of (appName) (pid: 1976): (appName) is hardened, (appName) doesn't have get-task-allow, (com.apple.debugserver) is a declared debugger(com.apple.debugserver) is not a declared read-only debugger`

Set Build settings of `CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS` to YES for Debug Level.

Answer (score -2):

Untick the debug executable.

Edit Scheme > Run > Debug executable

Comment: Not a solution as you won't be able to debug the app then.

Comment: @BaconPancakes well, it is still a solution for the problem of "Could not attach to pid: "####" - Lost Connection".

Comment: Not really. This issue is only present in debug schemes and removing the debug functionality is akin to handling the symptom instead of the root cause. A solution needs to fix the issue while making it possible to debug builds, otherwise it holds no value.